# Issue when calling wordpress function in Moodle

Tags: php, wordpress, moodle

I have a moodle system. I want to call the `wp_signon` function in my Moodle code. This auto signs in the user into WordPress from Moodle, so that the user can view our private blog posts. From his Moodle login, i know the user's WordPress credentials.

To call this function, I need to include the `wp-load.php` file. I believe `wp-load.php` includes all the wordpress functions. Both wordpress and Moodle have the `get_users()` and `get_context()` functions in them. This throws an error, saying that that cannot declare 2 functions with the same name. Also, `get_users()` and `get_context()` functions are not used by `wp_signon()`.

How do I solve this problem? Is there any other file that i can include instead of`wp_load.php`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this, because as you noted, both Moodle and WordPress have conflicting function names: get_users() and get_context(), so you can't conveniently load one system within the other.

Here's one way to work around that:

- When user logs into Moodle, automatically trigger a remote HTTP call to your WordPress site, requesting that the user is also logged in there.
- Write a WordPress plugin that verifies the log in request from Moodle, and log the user in. You might want to look at `wp_signon()` and `wp_set_auth_cookie()` functions and see how authentication for a specific user can be done programmatically.

Sounds very simple, but implementing that is very complicated, if you want the whole thing to be secure.

I'd suggest that you look into [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/), which is a standard on how to securely implement remote authorization. The idea is similar to what I wrote above, but it has much more details on how to securely verify the requests.